# Linear Programming with 3 variables

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the optimal solution for maximizing $X_1 + 2X_2 + 3X_3$ subject to the constraints that:

1. $X_1 + X_2 + X_3 \leq 9$,
2. $-X_1 + 2X_2 + 5X_3 \leq 15$,
3. $X_1 \geq 0$
4. $X_2 \geq 0$.

My answer is $17$. I think this is wrong.

Comment: Just check it using one of million apps for linear programming.

Answer (score 1):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize%20x%2B2*y%2B3*z%20subject%20to%20x%2By%2Bz%3C%3D9%2C%20-x%2B2*y%2B5*z%3C%3D15%2Cx%3E%3D0%2Cy%3E%3D0) would tend to say you're correct. You can solve it with one one of the million linear programming packages out there (CVX, linprog in Matlab for example).

Comment: Well they are a bit expensive for me. Im trying to sole be hand.

Comment: You can use GLPK in octave similarly, which is free: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Linear-Programming.html

Answer (score 0):

It is correct. But there exists more than one solution. If $x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \mathbb R$, then the number of solutions goes to infinity.

Two possible solutions:

$1) \ \  x_1=3;x_2=4;x_3=2$

$2) \ \ x_1=4;x_2=2;x_3=4$

Comment: yes I have 17 and 20.

Comment: Not sure which one is correct. Excel is giving me both answers?

Comment: The objetive function has the value 17 and 20 ? In both cases you can check, if the condition are true. Just insert in both cases the values for $x_1,x_2$ and $x_3$

Comment: constraints are : X1 + X2 + X3 <= 9; ----------1
-1X1 + 2X2 + 5X3 <= 15; X1 >= 0; X2 >= 0.
2X2 + 5X3 <= 15+X1----------------2
since, X1 + X2 + X3 <= 9;
let put X1=X2=X3=3
from constraints 2
6+15<=18
it is false,so X1=X2=X3=3 not possible
keeping in mind the constraints 2 put, X1=4, X2=2,X3=3
from constraint 1
19<=19 (true)
we have to maximize X1 + 2X2 + 3X3;
its maximum value is possible when X1=4, X2=2 ,X3=3
maximum value=4+4+9=17
9<=9 (true)
from constraints 2

Comment: because I have to maximize the value.

Comment: Do you think that 17 will be the best answer?

Comment: Yes, I think 17 is the best answer. But in general there is a algorithm, which helps you to find the solution. It is called the Simplex-algorithm. Maybe you have heard about it.

Comment: Calculus. Thank you very much for your help. You are correct!!!

Comment: You are welcome.